# How can I conditionally format a cell in column E based on the value of column F?

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

I have a column of string data that needs to be manipulated with an arrayformula in order to be ranked.  I can set this column up beside it and see the correct rankings.

If my data is in column E and my ranks are in column F, how can I format a cell in column E if the value of the adjacent cell is 1?

I have tried "Custom formula is" =F1 with a range of F1:F100, and also thought perhaps I could use something like `=INDIRECT("F"*row())=1` but I have not yet had any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the range you have is `E2:F`, the formula you need is:

```
=$F2=1
```

[image: Conditional formatting based on another column/cell]

### Pro Tip

An **advanced version** would be:

```
=AND($F2=1, $E2<>"")
```

*(Please test and compare both formulas using `0` instead of `1` to understand the full potential of the advanced formula)*

[image: Advanced conditional formatting based on another column/cell]

Comment: Even when using your solution here I did not see the result.  It appears that my efforts were originally suppressed by another conditional formatting rule.  Thank you for your answer, I have it working now.

Comment: _"...my efforts were originally suppressed by another conditional formatting rule"_.  I see. The order of the rules is very important. Glad it worked for you.